# ComboBox Keypress and transferring data from excel user form to sheet table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to create a small inventory system using excel, and I would like to use a macro to add a new record. My table and userform is in place, however, I have several issues.

First is that I'm unable to "lock" my comboboxes. I've tried locking it through its properties, however, the result is I'm now unable to select an item from the list. (The comboboxes are prepopulated). I have a button within my sheet (Add New Record) and it contains a code:

```
UserForm1.ComboBox1.List = Array("HO", "SI", "SV", "PTSF")
UserForm1.ComboBox2.List = Array("AP", "FU", "GE", "IT")
UserForm1.Show
```

And on my combobox:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
If KeyAscii = 8 Or KeyAscii = 127 Then
KeyAscii = 0
Else
End If
end sub
```

The code on my combobox does not work, and what I would like to happen is to lock it so that nothing can be typed or edited.

Second problem is that I don't know how to call my table, and insert the data on my userform to it. I've tried this earlier:

```
sheet1.table1.Lastrow = userform1.textbox1.value
```

but obviously it does not work :(

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Combobox: it has an enabled property, why not manipulate through that?  Insert data: there is no lastrow property in excel, also you need to refer to a cell to insert into.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, Hello, I've tried those properties, the result is that I'm unable to click it any longer. What I would like to happen is that the user should only be able to choose from the list, and won't be able to delete or edit it. As for the code, I've tried this:   Dim lRow As Long Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("HO Database")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    With ws
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.cboClass.Value  End With. However, this code does not work. It does not select my table and add the values on the last data :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem with this codes:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim lr As ListRow

Set ws = Sheets("HO Database")
Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
Set lr = lo.ListRows.Add

lr.Range(1, 1).Value = Me.ComboBox2.Value
lr.Range(1, 2).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
lr.Range(1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox9.Value
lr.Range(1, 4).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
lr.Range(1, 5).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
lr.Range(1, 6).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
lr.Range(1, 7).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
lr.Range(1, 8).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
lr.Range(1, 9).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
lr.Range(1, 10).Value = Me.TextBox7.Value
lr.Range(1, 11).Value = Me.TextBox8.Value
```

Hope someone can find this useful.